# the fastest way to get the LAST FOLDER in a path that also includes a filename?

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I get the last folder name (without the filename) from the following path using regex (in Javascript)?

```
c:\folder1\folder2\last_folder\filename.ext
```

I'm looking for the most efficient solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `"c:\\folder1\\folder2\\last_folder\\filename.ext".split('\\').reverse()[1];`

Comment: @Yoshi: That's not the fastest, but the shortest solution :-)

Comment: @Bergi You're right, of course ;)

Comment: @Yoshi: Thank you very much. Your answer is excellent for my case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var path = 'c:\\folder1\\folder2\\last_folder\\filename.ext';

var folder = path.replace( /.+\\(.+)\\[^\\]+$/, '$1' );
```